# How key_derivation and key_verification functions are implemented of a 7-zip archive's encryption mechanism?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, 7zip, password-recovery, cryptanalysis

I am curious about how password recovery works for password protected files. `And I want to know the exact flow of the 7-zip encryption mechanism.`

`7-zip` uses AES-256 encryption algorithm in CBC mode, to encrypt files or a folder. The key is generated from user supplied pass-phrase based on SHA-256 hash function. The SHA-256 is executed 2<sup>19</sup> (524,288) times to increase the cost of exhaustive search. Also, to help reduce the risk of dictionary attacks, salt is appended to original pass-phrase before generating hash.

My First question is `how does key_derivation function work to generate a 256-bit key` ? What is importance of IV for AES CBC mode and how it is generated?

My second and `most important question` is how key is verified to decrypt the 7-zip archive ? I mean how does its key_verification function work ?

Comment: Have you tried to contact one of the authors? Documentation about 7zip is very (very) sparse, and the source code is - for lack of a better word - shit.

Comment: @ owlstead,   Sir, I did not try to contact any authors. Just few days back i started to googled it, but i am not founding any technical documents relevant to 7-zip encryption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key derivation function is in the source of file `7zAes.cpp`, it's called:

```
void CKeyInfo::CalculateDigest()
```

and it creates the key using a proprietary (rather dull) mechanism.

I haven't been able to find the `key_verification` method yet, if it exists. I'll let you know if I do find it.

Comment: Documentation - including the specifications of the 7zip container format - seems to be missing in action. I even haven't had the pleasure to find a single source code comment in the crypto libs.

Comment: I agree with you, I went through the same code to know how key is generated. But two things i didn't get actually.                         First, since numRounds is calculated using "NumCyclesPower" which is initiated to zero. Then how this "for (UInt64 round = 0; round < numRounds; round++) " loop is supposed to run 2^19 times ?

Comment: Second, pass-phrase is appended without any encoding (i.e. UTF-16) mechanism. Does it means 7-zip does not using any encoding mechanism to generate a long string input message for SHA-256?

Comment: The inputs for the `Sha256_Update` is all bytes, `Password` seems to be a `CByteArray`, but I cannot directly see where it is set, and with this code base I would not know where to look for that either.